# Patching custom pipeline parameters in project level config file

Tags: configuration, helix, site-configuration

I have created a custom pipeline in a Foundation level Helix module. At the moment it has a single processor which can have multiple parameter configuration elements.

In my project layer, I want to patch this configuration to supply a new set of parameters for the existing pipeline. For some reason only the last parameter is getting patched.

**Foundation module config:**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <getCustomTaggingPageData>
        <processor type="Acme.Foundation.Tagging.Pipelines.GetUserProfileData, Acme.Foundation.Tagging">
          <variablesMapping hint="raw:AddMapping">
          </variablesMapping>
        </processor>
      </getCustomTaggingPageData>
    <getCustomTaggingEventData>
  </getCustomTaggingEventData>
</pipelines>
```

**Project module config:**

```
<configuration
  xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" 
  xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <pipelines>
        <getCustomTaggingPageData>
          <processor type="Acme.Foundation.Tagging.Pipelines.GetUserProfileData, Acme.Foundation.Tagging">
            <variablesMapping hint="raw:AddMapping">
              <mapping variableName="[ui:LoggedStatus]" profileProperty="Core:LoggedStatus" />
              <mapping variableName="[ui:User]" profileProperty="Core:User" />
              <mapping variableName="[ui:Email]" profileProperty="Core:EmailId" />
              <mapping variableName="[ui:Gender]" profileProperty="{0AE264FA-8D8F-48BC-8AC3-18B7F54F0DB9}" conditionalValue="mr?m:f" />
              <mapping variableName="[ui:PostalCode]" profileProperty="{D6BA91E2-F7E4-45CC-8FBB-25C2193536AE}" />
              <mapping variableName="[ui:City]" profileProperty="{05665E10-F5E6-4CD3-8159-B682D7972936}" />
              <mapping variableName="[ui:Birthday]" profileProperty="{A465D2A8-3866-4BCC-8352-A106F8C58A92}" dataType="System.DateTime" formatString="yyyy" />
            </variablesMapping>
          </processor>
        </getCustomTaggingPageData>
      </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Output from ShowConfig.aspx**

```
<getCustomTaggingPageData patch:source="Foundation.Tagging.config">
  <processor type="Acme.Foundation.Tagging.Pipelines.GetUserProfileData, Acme.Foundation.Tagging" patch:source="Sitecore.Project.Overrides.config">
    <variablesMapping hint="raw:AddMapping" patch:source="Sitecore.Project.Overrides.config">
      <mapping variableName="[ui:Birthday]" profileProperty="{A465D2A8-3866-4BCC-8352-A106F8C58A92}" patch:source="Sitecore.Project.Overrides.config" conditionalValue="mr?m:f" dataType="System.DateTime" formatString="yyyy"/>
    </variablesMapping>
  </processor>
</getCustomTaggingPageData>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the extra `<settings>` node in your project module config, at the moment you're not patching anything but inserting a new entry within the `<settings>` node (and it's probably not where you're looking in showconfig.aspx)

```xml
<configuration
  xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" 
  xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <getCustomTaggingPageData>
        <processor type="Acme.Foundation.Tagging.Pipelines.GetUserProfileData, Acme.Foundation.Tagging">
          <variablesMapping hint="raw:AddMapping">
            <mapping variableName="[ui:LoggedStatus]" profileProperty="Core:LoggedStatus" />
            <mapping variableName="[ui:User]" profileProperty="Core:User" />
            <mapping variableName="[ui:Email]" profileProperty="Core:EmailId" />
            <mapping variableName="[ui:Gender]" profileProperty="{0AE264FA-8D8F-48BC-8AC3-18B7F54F0DB9}" conditionalValue="mr?m:f" />
            <mapping variableName="[ui:PostalCode]" profileProperty="{D6BA91E2-F7E4-45CC-8FBB-25C2193536AE}" />
            <mapping variableName="[ui:City]" profileProperty="{05665E10-F5E6-4CD3-8159-B682D7972936}" />
            <mapping variableName="[ui:Birthday]" profileProperty="{A465D2A8-3866-4BCC-8352-A106F8C58A92}" dataType="System.DateTime" formatString="yyyy" />
          </variablesMapping>
        </processor>
      </getCustomTaggingPageData>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

I would also suggest that you add additional attributes to your processor to make your patching simpler between foundation and project layer, which I [previously blogged about](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/03/15/helix-config-patch/).

**Foundation Module Config**

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <getCustomTaggingPageData>
        <processor name="GetUserProfileData" type="Acme.Foundation.Tagging.Pipelines.GetUserProfileData, Acme.Foundation.Tagging">
          <variablesMapping hint="raw:AddMapping">
          </variablesMapping>
        </processor>
      </getCustomTaggingPageData>
    <getCustomTaggingEventData>
  </getCustomTaggingEventData>
</pipelines>
```

**Project Module Config**

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <getCustomTaggingPageData>
        <processor name="GetUserProfileData">
          <variablesMapping>
            <mapping variableName="[ui:LoggedStatus]" profileProperty="Core:LoggedStatus" />
            ...
          </variablesMapping>
        </processor>
      </getCustomTaggingPageData>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Note that we do not specify the `type` on our project module config. This will mean that if you change the type signature you no longer need to change it in 2 places and the configuration remains only in the foundation layer.

Comment: Good catch - I completely missed that `<settings>` node. This is the right answer - removing mine

Comment: Hi jammykam thanks for the answer! I found I had to also use @Richard Seal's technique of using the hint as well to make this work.

Answer (score 4):

This is down to how Sitecore patches child items. The same thing happens if you try to patch the `publish:end` configuration to add your site in. The problem is that because each of your `mapping` entries are effectively the same and don't contain any patching hints, each row patches the one above.

To solve that you can add a `hint` attribute to each row like this:

```
<configuration
  xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" 
  xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <pipelines>
        <getCustomTaggingPageData>
          <processor type="Acme.Foundation.Tagging.Pipelines.GetUserProfileData, Acme.Foundation.Tagging">
            <variablesMapping hint="raw:AddMapping">
              <mapping hint="LoggedStatus" variableName="[ui:LoggedStatus]" profileProperty="Core:LoggedStatus" />
              <mapping hint="User" variableName="[ui:User]" profileProperty="Core:User" />
              <mapping hint="Email" variableName="[ui:Email]" profileProperty="Core:EmailId" />
              <mapping hint="Gender" variableName="[ui:Gender]" profileProperty="{0AE264FA-8D8F-48BC-8AC3-18B7F54F0DB9}" conditionalValue="mr?m:f" />
              <mapping hint="PostalCode" variableName="[ui:PostalCode]" profileProperty="{D6BA91E2-F7E4-45CC-8FBB-25C2193536AE}" />
              <mapping hint="City" variableName="[ui:City]" profileProperty="{05665E10-F5E6-4CD3-8159-B682D7972936}" />
              <mapping hint="Birthday" variableName="[ui:Birthday]" profileProperty="{A465D2A8-3866-4BCC-8352-A106F8C58A92}" dataType="System.DateTime" formatString="yyyy" />
            </variablesMapping>
          </processor>
        </getCustomTaggingPageData>
      </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

When patching, Sitecore will see the `hint` attribute and this time add each line as a new line.

This is the same way that we would patch in the `sites` node on the `publish:end` handler:

```
<event name="publish:end">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
        <sites hint="list">
            <site hint="mysitename1">mysitename1</site>
            <site hint="mysitename2">mysitename2</site>
        </sites>
    </handler>
</event>
```

Without the `hint` there, these would just replace the `website` entry from the default config, and `mysitename2` would override `mysitename1`.